# Moongoose interrogation for NOT operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I'm trying to query the database so that it returns to the user of the shipments in which their id is not the same as that of the sender or that of the recipient.

```
Delivery.aggregate([{
    $match:{
      $and:[
        {startPlace:{$regex:".*"+start}},
        {endPlace:{ $regex:".*"+end}},
        {idSender: { $ne: req.user._id }},
        {idRecipient: { $ne: req.user._id }},
        {status:'Accettata'}
      ]      
    }
  }])
  .then(deliveryList=>{
//
    }
```

But the `$ne: req.user._id` don't work because if I'm the sender mongoose return me the delivery. How can I fix it?